# Join returning 2 rows when I when it to only ever return 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query and due to the following part:

```
        **LEFT JOIN dbo.Employee Mgr ON 
        (Pos.PPOSRP = Mgr.APOSNO AND Mgr.AACCT = Emp.AACCT)**
```

multiple records are being returned. Although it is valid data, I only ever need one record to be returned through this join. How could I change this accordingly?

```
        FROM dbo.Employee as Emp
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Position Pos ON Emp.APOSNO = Pos.PPOSNO
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Location Loc ON Emp.ALOCN = Loc.LCODE
        **LEFT JOIN dbo.Employee Mgr ON 
        (Pos.PPOSRP = Mgr.APOSNO AND Mgr.AACCT = Emp.AACCT)**
        where Emp.AEMPNO = '004635'
        ORDER BY Emp.AEMPNO
```

Comment: Do you mean 1 record in total i.e. whole query should return only 1 row?

Comment: Inner join instead of left joining that table and what do you get?

Comment: So one employee has more than one manager? But you only want one record (so either only one of a person's managers or a string containing all their names)? Then aggregate your results accordingly (i.e. use GROUP BY).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you have a variety of options, you can for instance do this:

```
FROM dbo.Employee as Emp
LEFT JOIN dbo.Position Pos ON Emp.APOSNO = Pos.PPOSNO
LEFT JOIN dbo.Location Loc ON Emp.ALOCN = Loc.LCODE
OUTER APPLY 
    (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM dbo.Employee Mgr 
    WHERE Mgr.APOSNO = Pos.PPOSRP AND Emp.AACCT = Mgr.AACCT) Mgr
where Emp.AEMPNO = '004635'
ORDER BY Emp.AEMPNO
```

If you want to return the first row only ordered by something, you can just insert ORDER BY as normally inside the OUTER APPLY.

Comment: Thanks very much Kahn, that did the trick and gave me the result I was after.

Answer (score 0):

You are joining back on the Employee table to get the data of, I suppose, the employee's manager or responsible. If the condition:

```
Pos.PPOSRP = Mgr.APOSNO AND Mgr.AACCT = Emp.AACCT
```

...selects two rows, then you should verify why it is doing so. It is obviously insufficient to isolate just one row on that table. You probably have to add some other condition in AND to select the one you want. Maybe the position has been covered by two different persons in different times, then you probably have to ADD some condition to select the one that interests the time frame of your SELECT statement.

As a side note, I wonder why you are sorting on the AEMPNO when you say you expect to have only one row in the result set.